# How can I display a language according to the user's browser's language inside this code?

Tags: php, browser

How can I display a language according to the user's browser's language inside this mini-framework for my multilingual website?

Basically, it has to display the default language of the user if there's no cookies.

Example of **index.php:** (rendered output)

```
<h2><?php echo l('tagline_h2'); ?></h2>
```

**common.php:** (controller of which language to output)

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

//use appropiate lang.xx.php file according to the value of the $lang
switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

  case 'es':
  $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
  break;

  case 'tw':
  $lang_file = 'lang.tw.php';
  break;

  case 'cn':
  $lang_file = 'lang.cn.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
}

//translation helper function
function l($translation) {
 global $lang;
 return $lang[$translation]; }

include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

Example of **/languages/lang.en.php:** (where multilingual content is being stored)

```
<?php
$lang = array(
 'tagline_h2' => '...',
```

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+language+php

Comment: @Gordon, it says "in this mini-framework".

Comment: What's your question then? Do you want to know *how to get the browser language* (duplicate) or do you want to know *where to put the code for getting the browser language*?

Answer (score 1):

[I think you are looking for this](http://snipplr.com/view/2807/get-the-browser-language/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is very good class for checking and even getting best match against supported languages:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6539